# How to add pagination to <asp:GridView>

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination to an `<asp:GridView>` in an application I'm working on.

This is what I've tried before running into an issue.

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="Contacts" ContextTypeName="Xrm.XrmServiceContext" TableName="ContactSet" runat="server"/>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvContacts" DataSourceID="Contacts" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        runat="server" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
        UseAccessibleHeader="true" OnPreRender="gvContacts_PreRender" AllowPaging="true" >

        <!-- irrelevant grid view content -->

    </asp:GridView>
```

If you ignore the the `AllowPaging="true"`, everything works fine (without the pagination feature). As soon as I include `AllowPaging="true"` I get the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: The method 'Count' is not supported.

How can I add pagination (size = 50) to my `<asp:GridView>`? Am I on the wrong track or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Gridview tag (sorting optional):

```
<asp:GridView AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize = "50" >
```

Somewhere you have a method "Count" referenced. Maybe the Linq method .Count() on something not countable (guess)?